# C: Use fwrite() with variables in program

Tags: c, variables, fwrite

Is there a way to use the fwrite method to read into a variable (a dynamic array) instead of a FILE *, or some alternative method that lets me do this? I need to read a binary file containing 16 bit chunks, but only read the last 12 bits of each chunk. Ideally I want something like:

```
fwrite(&(x+4),sizeof(x)-4,1,var);
```

But currently, I cant write into a var directly, only a file.

I know its possible using bitmasks/bitops, but this is a much simpler way so I'd prefer to use it if possible.

Comment: Do you mean fread?  Furthermore, you need to read a minimum of 1 byte chunks so you can't read 12 bits.

Comment: You should decide whether you want to write files, read files. Write to an array or read from an array. Your question consists of a mixture of reading/writing an array/file.

Comment: `use the fwrite method to read into a variable` ... what?!?

Comment: you probably need memcpy/memmove - copy a chunk of memory to another memory location

Comment: Read all the bits and ignore the ones you don't care about

Comment: Lets asssume you want to do this: read chunks of 16 bits from a file, and put the values of the 12 last bits of each chunk in an array. The important question is, do you want to end up with an array of the 12 bit integer values, e.g. ( a normal array for ease of examplification) int foo[10]; where foo[0] is the value of the first 12 bit of a chunk, or do you need to end up with a binary stream, e.g. unsigned char [10]; where 12 and 12 bits are laid out directly adjacently in this array ?

Comment: I want to end up with a binary stream.

Comment: Alright - there is no easy, shortcut or painless way to do that though.

Comment: @pmg This is for compression.I can't just ignore the bits, they need to be removed.
@Drakosha memcpy only takes chunks of bytes, not bits, so I cant use that.

Comment: Maybe you could open a null "file" for writing and set the buffer to what you want with full buffering.  That way you can indirectly write to the buffer using file methods.  I don't know if this would be a very good idea though but if that's what you want...

Comment: @Ankit:  No C library function moves bits around.  You'll have to do that yourself; write yourself a function that take four 16-bit values and compresses them into 3.  Use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` to move bytes around inside memory; `fwrite()` does nothing those don't except write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

No, `fwrite` writes to something that an be accessed like a file (FILE*).

Perhaps you want to use `sprintf` to format data into a string?

Answer (score 0):

C is byte oriented, not bit oriented.

read two 16 bit ints and combine them to 24 bits (3 bytes) by shaving off the top 4 bits.

```
for(;;) {
  uint8_t current;
  uint16_t d[2];
  if(fread(d,sizeof d,2,my_file) != 2) //convert the int if it's in the 
                                        //oposite endian of your host.
     return;
   current = (d[0] & 0xff0) >> 4) ;
   if(fwrite(&current,1,1,my_outfile) != 1) //or store it in an array.
      return;
    current = (d[0] & 0xf) << 4;
    current |= (d[1] & 0xf00) >> 8) ;
    if(fwrite(&current,1,1,my_outfile) != 1) //or store it in an array.
       return;
     current = d[1] & 0xff;
     if(fwrite(&current,1,1,my_outfile) != 1) //or store it in an array.
        return;
 }
```

Alternativly read them one 16 bit int at a time:

```
int state = 0;
uint8_t current;
for(;;) {
  uint16_t d;
  if(fread(&d,sizeof d,1,my_file) != 1) //convert the int if it's in the 
                                        //oposite endian of your host.
     return;
   switch(state)
      case 0:
        current = (d & 0xff0) >> 4) ;
        if(fwrite(&current,1,1,my_outfile) != 1) //or store it in an array.
          return;
        current = (d & 0xf) << 4;
        state = 1;
        break;
     case 1;
        current |= (d & 0xf00) >> 8) ;
        if(fwrite(&current,1,1,my_outfile) != 1) //or store it in an array.
          return;
        current = d & 0xff;
        if(fwrite(&current,1,1,my_outfile) != 1) //or store it in an array.
          return;
        state = 0;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read 16 bits. Assuming CHAR_BIT is 8 (the usual) that's 2 bytes:

```
size_t chk;
unsigned char data16[2];
chk = fread(data16, 2, 1, file);
if (chk != 1) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

Now, depending on endianness issues, just ignore the right 4 of those 16 bits read:

```
     data16 has, for instance: 01000101 11101011 (data16[0] == 0x45; data16[1] == 0xeb)
     and you want these bits:  ^^^^^.^^ ^..^^^.^
     so ... mask and shift!
```

```
/* mask and shift, bit by bit */
data12[0] = 0;
data12[0] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 7)) << 3;
data12[0] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 6)) << 2;
data12[0] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 5)) << 1;
data12[0] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 4)) << 0;
data12[1] = 0;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 3)) << 7;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 1)) << 6;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[0] & (1 << 0)) << 5;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[1] & (1 << 7)) << 4;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[1] & (1 << 4)) << 3;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[1] & (1 << 3)) << 2;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[1] & (1 << 2)) << 1;
data12[1] |= !!(data16[1] & (1 << 0)) << 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED TO ADD BETTER ANSWER**

From the comments, it looks like you want to compress a buffer -- an array of 16-bit ints by stripping off 4 bits and packing them together, right?

This code should do the trick:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int   UINT32 ;
typedef unsigned short UINT16 ;

void compress( UINT16 *buf , int *cnt )
{
  UINT16 *src   = buf        ; // where we're copying from
  UINT16 *tgt   = buf        ; // where we're copying to
  UINT16 *limit = buf + *cnt ; // endpoint address
  UINT16  bits  = 0x0000     ;
  int     state = 0          ;

  while ( src < limit )
  {
    switch ( state )
    {
    case 0 :
      bits    = (*src++ & 0x0FFF ) <<  4 ;
      state   = 1 ;
      break ;
    case 1 :
      bits   |= (*src   & 0x0F00 ) >>  8 ;
      *tgt++  = bits ;
      bits    = (*src++ & 0x00FF ) <<  8 ;
      state   = 2 ;
      break ;
    case 2 :
      bits   |= (*src   & 0x0FF0 ) >>  4 ;
      *tgt++  = bits ;
      bits    = (*src++ & 0x000F ) << 12 ;
      state   = 3 ;
      break ;
    case 3 :
      bits   |= (*src++ & 0x0FFF ) ;
      *tgt++  = bits ;
      bits    = 0x000 ;
      state   = 0 ;
      break ;
    }
  }

  if ( state != 0 )
  {
    *tgt++ = bits ;
  }

  // hand back the new size ;
  *cnt = (tgt - buf ) ;

  while ( tgt < limit )
  {
    *tgt++ = 0x0000 ;
  }

  return ;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
  UINT16 buf[] = { 0xF123 , 0xE456 , 0xD789 , 0xCABC , 0xBDEF , } ;
  int    bufl  = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf) ;

  compress( buf , &bufl ) ;

  // buf now looks like { 0x1234 , 0x5678 , 0x9ABC , 0xDEF0 , 0x0000 }

  return 0 ;
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you actually wantg to **read** 16-bit structures from a file and that have 12 interesting bits and 4 unused (or not very interesting) bits, and you want to avoid bit-twiddling, you can use *bit fields*.

Note that implementations get a **lot** of leeway under the standard for how this stuff works, so it's not portable in the least: you'll probably need to tweak structure alignment and possibly field order, depending on the underlying CPU. You'll note my use of `#pragma pack(2)` to coerce the structure into a 16-bit size — that works in Visual Studio 2010 C++. YMMV and all that.

[You *sure* you don't want to just mask off the bits you don't want?]

At any rate, once you deal with all that, something like the following code should work for you:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(2) // necessary to get correct alignment
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short unused :  4 ;
    unsigned short value  : 12 ;
} CHUNK ;
#define BUFFER_CHUNKS ((size_t)8192)

void process( FILE*input )
{
  CHUNK *buf    = (CHUNK*) calloc( BUFFER_CHUNKS , sizeof(CHUNK) ) ;
  size_t bufl   = BUFFER_CHUNKS * sizeof(CHUNK) ;
  int    chunks = 0 ;

  while ( 0 > (chunks=(int)fread( (void*)buf , sizeof(CHUNK) , BUFFER_CHUNKS , input ) ) )
  {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < chunks ; ++i )
    {
      int value = buf[i].value ;
      printf( "%d: %d\n" , i , value ) ;
    }
  }

  return ;
}
```

Good Luck!